# getfocus to elements on screen after performing swipeUp() android-espresso automation

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am performing swipeUp() on GridView using android automation as below,

onView(withId(R.id.grid)).perform(swipeUp()); It is working perfectly.

The above grid has TableLayout generated dynamically. I cannot perform scrollTo() on GridView,TableLayout,TableRowLayout using onView or onData as I dont have ScrollView defined in hierarchy, it is throwing PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: com.app.mobile:id/grid'.

When I tried to access the TableLayout,TableRowLayout contents after swipeUp() it is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException. Without swipeUp() two rows of table are visible and the isDisplayed() event run perfectly but I want to access remaining rows.

I want to getfocus to elements after swipeUP().

Code:

```
expMonitor =getInstrumentation().addMonitor(MyActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    expActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(expMonitor, 3000);
    Matcher<View> viewMatcher_layout = findChildof(withId(R.id.grid), 2);
    Matcher<View> viewMatcher_table = findChildof(viewMatcher_layout, 1);
    onView(withId(R.id.grid)).perform(swipeUp());
    for(int currentIndex = 0;currentIndex<5;currentIndex++){
        Matcher<View> viewMatcher_row_layout = findChildof(viewMatcher_table, currentIndex);
onView(findChildof(viewMatcher_table,currentIndex)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    Matcher<View> viewMatcher_text = findChildof(viewMatcher_row_layout, 0);
    if (findChildof(viewMatcher_text, 0).equals(notNullValue()))
     onView(findChildof(viewMatcher_text, 0)).check(matches((isDisplayed())));
    if (findChildof(viewMatcher_text, 1).equals(notNullValue()))
     onView(findChildof(viewMatcher_text, 1)).check(matches((isDisplayed())));
    if (findChildof(viewMatcher_text, 2).equals(notNullValue()))
     onView(findChildof(viewMatcher_text, 2)).check(matches((isDisplayed())));
    }
```

Comment: try to provide at least some of the code you're working with so others can reproduce exactly your issue and possibly provide an answer

Comment: for currentIndex<2, without swipe its running but after swipe, its showing perfectly viewMatcher_layout on screen with 5 rows but failing all for loop code.